# Keras - Look up an embedding

Tags: python, keras, word-embedding

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to look up the word embeddings for each word from a sequence. This is a sequence of numbers generated from text.

**Background:**

My sequence (of shape (200,)) looks something like this:

```
50, 2092, 3974,  398,   10, 9404,    5, 1001, 3975,   15,  512... <snip>
```

These number represent a word from a vocabulary (of 10000 words). I have an some embedding weights that I created using the negative sampling method found [here](http://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/word2vec-keras-tutorial/).

The extracted embedding weights are of shape (10000 , 106) of which I can load into a new embedding layer.

I want to look up each number in the sequence from this new embedding layer with the loaded weights and have it return 200 vectors of size 106 corresponding to the sequence.

**Here is what I have done so far:**

```
embedding_weights = np.genfromtxt('embedding_weights.csv', delimiter=',')

    input_layer = Input(shape=(200,), name='text_input')
    embedding = Embedding(input_length=200, input_dim=vocabulary_size, output_dim=106, 
                           name='embedding_layer', trainable=False, weights=[embedding_weights])
    embedded_text = embedding(input_layer)
```

Is this the correct way to look up the embeddings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that looks correct. To actually extract the embeddings, you can wrap the layers you defined in a `Model`:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding
from keras.models import Model

# Generate some random weights
embedding_weights = np.random.rand(10000, 106)
vocabulary_size = 10000

input_layer = Input(shape=(200,), name='text_input')
embedding = Embedding(input_length=200, input_dim=vocabulary_size, output_dim=106, 
                       name='embedding_layer', trainable=False, weights=[embedding_weights])
embedded_text = embedding(input_layer)

embedding_model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=embedded_text)

# Random input sequence of length 200
input_sequence = np.random.randint(0,10000,size=(1,200))
# Extract the embeddings by calling the .predict() method
sequence_embeddings = embedding_model.predict(input_sequence)
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you for clearing that up, I would have never though of using predict to extract the resulting embeddings. Its great that keras handles the embedding lookup in such a concise way.

Comment: You're welcome, the keras api is indeed lovely to work with.

Comment: Note that you can alternatively use `K.function()` to extract the embeddings. See eg [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51677631/keras-tensorflow-get-predictions-or-output-of-all-layers-efficiently/51678174#51678174)

Comment: How can I input this sequence_embeddings to next layer ?